# SMTP does not work with Business Email GMAIL

Tags: email, smtp

I am currently using google workspace for my business. I have a website where I have a form, and once the user clicks submits, I send the data to my email. This works perfectly with my regular personal email, however when I try to send it to my business email, the email never delivers.

I currently use GoDaddy as a web hosting service, and my domain is bought through Google Domains, and the email service is through Google. Am I missing something here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after digging around massively, here is the solution.

You have to go to GoDaddy's DNS settings, and add the MX records of Google's email servers. After including those MX records, you must go log into CPanel. When in CPanel, you go to Email Routing, and enable **REMOTE MAIL EXCHANGER**.

After enabling the remote mail exchanger, you need to add the MX records in CPanel, under Zone Editor.

Once all that's complete, my gmail is now receiving email from my hosted website thats on GoDaddy.